# convert integers back after converting them into bitsets and OR -ing them in java

Tags: java

I perform the operation for two integers... consider I do

A = (1 << 6) OR (1 << 7)

Is there a way that I can get the integers 6 and 7 from A after doing the OR operation?

Please let me know if the answer has been answered anywhere else.

Comment: This is a one way operation, I doubt you can ever find the operands of the OR operation given only its result.

Comment: Nothing easier than that: `System.out.println(6); System.out.println(7);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always bitshifting 1 then you can do the following.

```
int a = (1 << 6) ^ (1 << 7);
int temp = a;
for(int i=0;i<32;i++) {
    if((temp&1)==1) 
        System.out.println("number: " + i);
    temp = temp >> 1;
}
```

Output:

```
 number: 6
 number: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your expression isn't valid Java and not knowing what you want to do, but assuming that you wish to ascertain which bits are "set", you can do this with `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros()`, eg.:

```
Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( A & 64 );   // 1<<6 == 64
Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( A & 128 );  // 1<<7 == 128
```

This would get you the ints 6 and 7 respectively.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the individual bits by testing them:

```
bit6 = (A >> 6) & 1;
bit7 = (A >> 7) & 1;
```

The integer 6 is in the bitset if bit6 == 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value=(1<<7) | (1<<6);

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
if(value==0) sb.append("0");
else while(value!=0) {
  int b=Integer.highestOneBit(value);
  if(b==1) sb.append("1");
  else
    sb.append("(1<<").append(Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(b)).append(')');
  value-=b;
  if(value>0) sb.append(" | ");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```